# save data from all loop iterations in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops

the following is part of my code, when I run it, I find that data and data1 is only file B5.m, I would like to save all iterations (Example, B11.m to B55.m). finally, I want to add B11 from first folder with B11 from other folder and save it in new folder.

```
for i = 1:5
    for j=1:5
    name=['B',num2str(i),num2str(i),'.m'];  
    name1=['B',num2str(j),num2str(i),'.m']; 
    data=load([p,name]);
    data1=load([w,name1]);
    end
end
```

Comment: `name` for i = 1 and j = 1 will be equal to `name1` (name = B11 and name1 = B11)

Comment: yes, but name1 is file B11 from one folder and name is file B11 from other folder

Comment: So just use the `save` function with the two different folders. Also make sure you close `data` and `data1` for each `j` (hence add after `save1`, `close data;` `close data1;`)

Comment: can you plz just write it as code, I didnt get how to use save function :( !!

Comment: dose it help to save B11+B11 in new folder?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to input the entire data workspace that you load into a [`struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html). something like:

```
c=0;
for i = 1:5
for j=1:5
c=c+1;
name=['B',num2str(i),num2str(i),'.m'];  
name1=['B',num2str(j),num2str(i),'.m']; 
data=load([p,name]);
data1=load([w,name1]);

s=struct(c,data);
s1=struct(c,data1);

end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
save([p, name], 'data', '-ASCII')
save([w, name], 'data1', '-ASCII')
```

Comment: hi, thank you. but where can I find saving files. data still show only last iteration only

Comment: @hola p and w should include the path to where you want to save your files.